# Delete record in a table if it maps to a single record in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, query-optimization

Tables:

1. Customer table: Cust_ID
2. Customer group table: Cust_ID, Cust_Grp_ID

A customer can be part of multiple customer groups.
While deleting a customer group, customer should be deleted if it maps to the said customer group only. What is the most efficient performant query?

Solutions that I can think of:

1. Find customers which are not part of the customer group.
   Delete the customers who are part of the customer group but not present in the first query.
2. Delete the mapping from customer group table.
   Delete the customers who are not mapped to any customer group.
3. Join the tables, delete only the customers that have count of 1 and maps to said customer group?

Comment: Can you edit your question and share some simple data and the expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

Important things to question yourself:

- Do you want to automatically trigger a cleanup of users every time a delete of the customer group takes place? Or can there be batches of updates and you want to trigger it manually at the end of a batch of deletes.
- Do you need to run the same delete customer statements when a user is removed from his last customergroup, without a customergroup being deleted?
- What other functionalities are tied into the customer deletion process. I can imagine the customer id is refered in a lot of places in your model, so what is the impact of just removing the customer from the system. Is it not better to add a column is_active and put it to false?

If you are working with a relative small set of customers and customergroups, i would just create a trigger on any update/delete of the customer group table which removes all customers from the customer table which are not part of the customer group table. so that will be probably 2.